# How to Sort Output from several Log Files by date

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I have got output from several different log files:

```
logfile3
2010/07/21 15:28:52 INFO xxx
2010/07/21 15:31:25 INFO xxx
2010/07/21 15:31:25 DEBUG xxx

logfile1
2010/07/21 19:28:52 INFO xxx
2010/07/21 19:31:25 INFO xxx
2010/07/21 19:31:25 DEBUG xxx

logfile2
2010/07/21 13:28:52 INFO xxx
2010/07/21 13:31:25 INFO xxx
2010/07/21 13:31:25 DEBUG xxx
```

I would like to sort this output by date, but keep the name of the logfile above the log lines, so it should look like:

```
logfile2
2010/07/21 13:28:52 INFO xxx
2010/07/21 13:31:25 INFO xxx
2010/07/21 13:31:25 DEBUG xxx

logfile3
2010/07/21 15:28:52 INFO xxx
2010/07/21 15:31:25 INFO xxx
2010/07/21 15:31:25 DEBUG xxx

logfile1
2010/07/21 19:28:52 INFO xxx
2010/07/21 19:31:25 INFO xxx
2010/07/21 19:31:25 DEBUG xxx
```

Do you have any idea how to sort output like this with bash commands, sed or awk?
Thanks a lot!

UPDATE:
This is the source of the output

```
for i in $( find log/ -iname *debug*.log -size +0 );do
if [ `grep -c 'ERROR' $i` -gt 0 ];then
 echo -e "\n$i"
 grep 'ERROR' --color=auto -A 5 -B 5 $i
fi
done
```

Martin

Comment: "I have got output from several different log files"... in a single file?

Comment: Do the times overlap?  If so how do you want the files reported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all.

I improved script from Dennis Williamson to sort errors by date. Each log file with error inside is saved in file named by the timestamp of last error occured. These files are later sorted and put together. There may be cleaner solutions for that than to use of temp files.

```
find log/ -iname "*debug*.log" -size +0 | while read -r file
do
    if grep -qsm 1 'ERROR' "$file"
    then
        echo -e "$i \t$file"
        errors=$(grep 'ERROR' --color=auto -C 5 "$file")
        #get the timestamp of last error occured
        time=$(echo $errors | head -n 1 | awk '{print $1" "$2}')
        timestamp=$(date -d "$time" +%s)
        #save it to temp file
        echo -e "\n$file\n$errors" > tmp/logs/$timestamp.$i
    fi
    let i++
done

#put files together
rm -f output.txt
for i in `ls tmp/logs/*|sort`;do cat $i >> output.txt ; rm  $i; done
```

Opinions and suggestions for improvement appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to get satisfactory results from this (as long as none of your filenames contain colons):

```
grep -C 5 --recursive 'ERROR' log/* | sort --field-separator=: --key=2
```

Each line will be prepended by the filename. Your output will look something like this:

```
logfile2:2010/07/21 13:28:52 INFO xxx
logfile2:2010/07/21 13:31:25 INFO xxx
logfile2:2010/07/21 13:31:25 DEBUG xxx

logfile3:2010/07/21 15:28:52 INFO xxx
logfile3:2010/07/21 15:31:25 INFO xxx
logfile3:2010/07/21 15:31:25 DEBUG xxx
etc.
```

You can use AWK to reformat that into the format that you show in your example:

```
grep -C 5 --recursive 'ERROR' log/* | sort --field-separator=: --key=2 |
    awk '{colon = match($0,":"); file = substr($0,1,colon - 1); 
    if (file != prevfile) {print "\n" file; prevfile = file}; 
    print substr($0,colon+1)}'
```

Here are several improvements to your script, in case you still use it:

```
find log/ -iname "*debug*.log" -size +0 | while read -r file
do
    if grep -qsm 1 'ERROR' "$file"
    then
        echo -e "\n$file"
        grep 'ERROR' --color=auto -C 5 "$file"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Nicholas-Knights-MacBook-Pro:~/logtest$ ls
logfile1 logfile2 logfile3
Nicholas-Knights-MacBook-Pro:~/logtest$ cat logfile*
2010/07/21 19:28:52 INFO xxx
2010/07/21 19:31:25 INFO xxx
2010/07/21 19:31:25 DEBUG xxx

2010/07/21 13:28:52 INFO xxx
2010/07/21 13:31:25 INFO xxx
2010/07/21 13:31:25 DEBUG xxx

2010/07/21 15:28:52 INFO xxx
2010/07/21 15:31:25 INFO xxx
2010/07/21 15:31:25 DEBUG xxx

Nicholas-Knights-MacBook-Pro:~/logtest$ for i in `ls logfile*` ; do printf "$i"; sort -n $i; printf '\n'; done
logfile1
2010/07/21 19:28:52 INFO xxx
2010/07/21 19:31:25 DEBUG xxx
2010/07/21 19:31:25 INFO xxx

logfile2
2010/07/21 13:28:52 INFO xxx
2010/07/21 13:31:25 DEBUG xxx
2010/07/21 13:31:25 INFO xxx

logfile3
2010/07/21 15:28:52 INFO xxx
2010/07/21 15:31:25 DEBUG xxx
2010/07/21 15:31:25 INFO xxx

Nicholas-Knights-MacBook-Pro:~/logtest$
```

Comment: Thank you, Nicholas, sorry if I was not clear. I want to sort output by date of the log lines, not by the file names - please see my question for the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

If you have you output already in a file (or script output) I'd go Perl:

```
$/=undef;
$t=<>;
@t=split(/\s*\n*(logfile.*)$/m,$t);
foreach $f (@t) {
    next unless $f;
    if($f =~ /^logfile/) {
      print $f;
    } else {
        print join("\n",sort (split(/\n/,$f))) . "\n\n";
   }
}
```

Or, a little more clean:

```
@lines = ();
while($t=<>) {
    if($t!~ /^2\d\d\d/) {
        print sort @lines if(scalar(@lines));
        @lines = ();
        print $t;
    }
    else {
      push @lines,$t;
   }
}
print sort @lines if(scalar(@lines));
```

Comment: No, it is from several files, I have updated the source script to the question. How can I use this script? Thank you!

Comment: It is from serveral files but you already have the output consolidated? If so, yes, my script might help. But it would be easier to make the sort inside your script.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{$NF=$NF" "FILENAME;}1' logfile*|sort -t" " -k1 -k2|awk 'NF==5{ h=$NF;$NF="";$0=h"\n"$0 }1'
logfile2
2010/07/21 13:28:52 INFO xxx
2010/07/21 13:31:25 DEBUG xxx
2010/07/21 13:31:25 INFO xxx
logfile3
2010/07/21 15:28:52 INFO xxx
2010/07/21 15:31:25 DEBUG xxx
2010/07/21 15:31:25 INFO xxx
logfile1
2010/07/21 19:28:52 INFO xxx
2010/07/21 19:31:25 DEBUG xxx
2010/07/21 19:31:25 INFO xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try rust-based tool [*Super Speedy Syslog Searcher*](https://crates.io/crates/super_speedy_syslog_searcher)

(assuming you have [rust installed](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install))

```
cargo install super_speedy_syslog_searcher
```

then

```
s4 logfile1 logfile2 logfile3
```

*HOWEVER...*

> but keep the name of the logfile above the log lines

`s4` cannot output that approach.

`s4` *can* write the name of the logfile to precede the log message.

```
$ s4 -wp logfile1 logfile2 logfile3
logfile2:2010/07/21 13:28:52 INFO xxx
logfile2:2010/07/21 13:31:25 INFO xxx
logfile2:2010/07/21 13:31:25 DEBUG xxx
logfile3:2010/07/21 15:28:52 INFO xxx
logfile3:2010/07/21 15:31:25 INFO xxx
logfile3:2010/07/21 15:31:25 DEBUG xxx
logfile1:2010/07/21 19:28:52 INFO xxx
logfile1:2010/07/21 19:31:25 INFO xxx
logfile1:2010/07/21 19:31:25 DEBUG xxx
```